# GWT with Glassfish 3/Hibernate - Request Factory Validation Tool Must Be Run

Tags: hibernate, gwt, glassfish-3, requestfactory

I have been learning GWT and Hibernate together for the last few weeks and wanted to throw up a demo on a local glassfish server (That is what our web app server is going to be, although if i cannot find the answer to this issue i may look into Tomcat or JBoss)

When i run my app on the standard local server (The Jetty Server used when I run it through eclipse) everything works fine - i have gotten the RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run error before but normally cleaning the project fixed it.

I have annotation processing turned on in my eclipse project - and haven't seen this error in a while. Every time i deploy my project to Glassfish I get the RequestFactory ValidationTool Must be run for RequestFactory error - I cannot figure out what to do about this.

Here's some things to take into account - I am new to Hibernate as well and am not sure if i have set up my persistence.xml file correctly - it is in the META-INF folder in the root of my src directory.  I believe it is setup correctly, but I am wondering if setting up the persistence xml incorrectly could produce that error as a side effect.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, this only happens when i deploy to the server, before I do that I use a Google Compile, I jar up my src directory and add it into my war/lib directory, then run an ant script to war it all up then manually deploy it onto Glassfish.  I don't think I missed any steps there but if I did please let me know.

---

in case anybody else has this problem, i got mine to work doing something a little funky

i followed the advice here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation as given in the response - but i had to tweak a few things

first i jarred up the /src file and added it into my war/WEB-INF/lib directory

i then created this shell script in my root directory as jar.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
    java \
    -cp war/WEB-INF/lib/myproj.jar:war/WEB-INF/lib/requestfactory-apt.jar:war/WEB-INF    /lib/requestfactory-server.jar \
    com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ValidationTool \
    myproj-validated.jar \
    com.myproj.client.MyprojRequestFactory
```

I then ran the jar.sh from a command line, moved the new jar file into my war/WEB-INF/lib directory, exported the whole project as a war file and launched it to glassfish and it actually worked. to my surprise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation

It's not related with Hibernate or anything else. The idea is, when you build your app for deployment, GWT wants you to run Request Factory validation tool. Otherwise, you won't be able to communicate with server from your client code, though everything will compile fine.